# Azure Api Manager cache-remove-value policy not removing the cache item

Tags: azure-api-management

I am caching certain values in my azure api manager policy and in certain cases remove the item to clean up the cache and retrieve the value back from the api.

Based on my experience, even after I remove the value using the cache-remove-value policy, my next api call still finds the value in the cache. Here is a sample code:

```
    <cache-store-value key="Key123" value="123" duration="300" />
    <cache-lookup-value key="Key123" variable-name="CacheVariable" />
    <cache-remove-value key="Key123" />
    <cache-lookup-value key="Key123" default-value="empty" variable-name="CacheVariable2" />
    <return-response>
        <set-status code="504" reason="" />
        <set-body>@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("CacheVariable2"))</set-body>
    </return-response>
```

This code basically returns empty or "123" in the body based on if the cache item with key Key123 was found after being removed or not. This always returns the value of the cached item, "123".

Did anyone experienced this issue or found a way to clean up the cache?

If I continously check in a Retry, I can see that the item is sometimes cleaned after 2 seconds, sometimes 1 minute. I think the delete call is an async or queued call in the background so that we can't really be sure if it's cleaned or not without continuously checking.

UPDATE:

As an actual solution for now, instead of deleting, I actually update the cache item with 1 second duration and a dirty value.

Comment: I will check to see if it is async, but that wouldn't surprise me.  Most of the time you wouldn't want to block  on this kind of operation as it makes a distributed call to the redis cache. Interestingly I would expect the update cache to do the same, so I'm not sure why you are seeing different behavior with your workaround.

Comment: The policy processing doesn't wait until the cache-remove-value is complete before continuing but the cache-store does.  So, the workaround works, but it seems to me that there should be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because cache removal request is asynchronous in regards to request processing pipeline, i.e. APIM does not wait for cache item to be removed before continuing with request, thus it is possible to still retrieve it right after removal request since it has not been sent yet.

Updated based on your scenario: why don't you try something like this then:

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
</inbound>
<backend>
    <retry condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 200)" count="10" interval="1">
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault("calledOnce", false))">
                <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="response">
                    <set-url>https://EXTERNAL-SERVICE-URL</set-url>
                    <set-method>GET</set-method>
                </send-request>
                <cache-store-value key="externalResponse" value="EXPRESSION-TO-EXTRACT-DATA" duration="300" />
                <!--... or even store whole response ...-->
                <cache-store-value key="externalResponse" value="@((IResponse)context.Variables["response"])" duration="300" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <cache-lookup-value key="externalResponse" variable-name="externalResponse" />

                <choose>
                     <when condition="@(context.Variables.ContainsKey("externalResponse"))">
                         <!-- Do something with cached data -->
                     </when>
                     <otherwise>
                         <!-- Call extenal service and store in cache again -->
                     </otherwise>
                 </choose>

                <set-variable name="calledOnce" value="@(true)" />
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
        <forward-request />
    </retry>
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
</outbound>
```

Comment: The issue with that is, APIM is not resurfacing the cache removal action as an async action. If I put "wait" policy around the cache removal, I get an exception that says only async/awaitable actions can be put in a "wait" clause.

Comment: Wait policy is a way to execute policies in parallel and continue when any or all complete. Such policies outside of wait would've still block request processing. Cache removal on the other hand never blocks request processing, nor does cache store value by the way. What is your scenario? Since you've updated cache with value generated during this request processing, that means that value is already available to you and there is no need to go to cache to get it.

Comment: My case:
I retrieve a data from an external service that will be used in the request on the backend. I don't know if the value is valid or not.
If the call succeeds, I cache the value, as it will be required for multiple calls in the next 5 minutes. If I call the external service everytime, it adds 2 seconds of overhead which I am trying to dodge.

During that 5 minutes, if the backend engine returns an invalid response, I clean the cache and return "retry" back to calling app, so that the next call will go and call the external service again to retrieve the updated value.

Comment: APIM does not allow more than one statement in <backend> area. If it did, I would simply refresh the value in the same pipeline, but I can't, that's the reason for returning RETRY back to calling app and handle this in the next call.

Comment: Updated the answer with policy sample.

Comment: Thanks Vitaliy, this actually helped me to come up with a solution for our case.